# How to write adb commands in windows 7 command prompt

Tags: java, android, adb

I have a big problem in the run of Android app in eclipse! When I finished developing my app, and right click on project>Run As>Android Application, I see a

```
[2013-03-04 15:36:25 - DeviceMonitor] Connection attempts: 1
[2013-03-04 15:36:28 - DeviceMonitor] Connection attempts: 2
[2013-03-04 15:36:25 - DeviceMonitor] Connection attempts: 3
```

in console window.

Then I opend my command-Prommpt (in Win 7 32-bit) and see

```
C:\user\saadati>
```

How I write adb commands in it? likes **adb kill-server** and etc.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

First go to Android-sdk Path -> (like D:\RAJESH-ANDROID\android-sdk\platform-tools) 
and execute the your commands like adb-kill server

```
like below :


Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7600]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\raj>cd D:\RAJESH-ANDROID\android-sdk\platform-tools

C:\Users\raj>d:

D:\RAJESH-ANDROID\android-sdk\platform-tools>adb kill-server

D:\RAJESH-ANDROID\android-sdk\platform-tools>adb start-server
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
* daemon started successfully *

D:\RAJESH-ANDROID\android-sdk\platform-tools>
```

Answer (score 8):

Add adb to your PATH and you'll be able to use adb commands anywhere in cmd, which is helpful for building apps and killing/starting the server quickly.

To do so, right-click on *Computer* in the start menu and click properties. Next, click on *Advanced system settings* on the left hand side of the window. Next, click *Enviroment Variables* on the window that pops up.

From here you get a list of user variables and system variables. Add a new system variable called **ADB_HOME**, with the value as the path to the platform-tools folder for your android sdk. Next, find the **Path** variable and add **%ADB_HOME%** to this string of values.

You'll now be able to use adb from anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Windows 7->Run->cmd-> go to platform-tools folder of the android sdk.

then type

adb kill-server
adb start-server

etc

Comment: how I go to platform-tools folder of the android sdk?

Comment: you need to use cd commands to change the directory? and cd.. to come out of the directory