# Can not start Android Device Monitor

Tags: android, android-studio

In Android Studio, when I am trying to start Android device Monitor it shows following error.

```
    E/BatteryStatsService: no controller energy info supplied     
    E/BatteryStatsService: modem info is invalid: ModemActivityInfo{ 
    mTimestamp=0 mSleepTimeMs=0 mIdleTimeMs=0 mTxTimeMs[]=[0, 0, 0, 0, 0] 
    mRxTimeMs=0 mEnergyUsed=0}
    E/BandwidthController: Updating quota globalAlert failed (No such file 
    or directory)
    E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
    E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
    E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
    E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
    E/Internal: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote 
    host
```

Even I tried start Android Studio with run as administrator/Restart/monitor.exe. Thanks in advance.

Comment: try to kill adb server [`adb kill server`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15201344/how-to-write-adb-commands-in-windows-7-command-prompt) and retry

Comment: thanks for the help  @n00dl3